# How to fix error in Django serializers.py fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

[image]I'm trying to send a post request from django app using rest framework but I keep having the following output:

```
{
    "user_name": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "email": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "company": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "state": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "city": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "address": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "phone_number": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "password_2": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I have the following blocks of code:

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
     path("register_user/", account_register, name="register")

]
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager,
                                        PermissionsMixin)

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django.core.mail import send_mail 

class CustomManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, user_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name,
                          **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class UserBase(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    license_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = CountryField(null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    #User status
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = CustomManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name']
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name: 'Accounts'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Accounts'
        
    def email_user(self, subject, message):
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            'florixhealthcare@gmail.com',
            [self.email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import UserBase


class registeration_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password_2 = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserBase
        fields = ['user_name', 'email',  'first_name', 'first_name', 'company', 
            'state', 'city', 'address', 'postcode', 'phone_number', 'password', 'password_2']
        extra_kwargs = {"password":{"write_only": True}}

    def save(self):
        account = UserBase(
            user_name = self.validated_data["user_name"],
            email = self.validated_data["email"],
            company = self.validated_data["company"],
            state = self.validated_data["state"],
            city = self.validated_data["city"],
            address = self.validated_data["address"],
            postcode = self.validated_data["postcode"],
            phone_number = self.validated_data["phone_number"],
            
        )
        password = self.validated_data["password"]
        password_2 = self.validated_data["password"]

        if password != password_2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password":"Passwords do not match"})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

views.py

```
@api_view(["POST",])
def account_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_serializer = registeration_serializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if register_serializer.is_valid():
            account = register_serializer.save()
            data["response"] = "Welcome! Your account has been successfully created."
            data["email"] = account.email
        
        else:
            data = register_serializer.errors
        return Response (data)
```

I haven't seen any error with code. I have search online but haven't seen any solution that works for me. How do I get over this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of data you're sending ?

Comment: The output you are getting is your field level validation thrown by your serializer `registeration_serializer()`. It simply means that you need to send these fields in you API request body. What is the API request body you are sending?

Comment: It shows because these fields required,  you can pass this fields

Comment: @Guillaume I tried to send the data based on the field I specified in serializers.py.` user_name, email, company` and I passed in their respective values on postman the out is that error. I get the error whether I passed in all the values, some of the values or none

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeet. I specified the fields in the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post some of the data you're testing with, but generally as the response says, it seems that you're not providing these mandatory fields in the post body.

To mark any field not required, you can simply add it explicitly in the serializer, for example:

```py
class MySerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    usern_name= serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

The `required=False` makes it not mandatory, also there is `allow_null` and others that you can find [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield)

Comment: Thanks so much @P. Naoum. I passed in all the fields I specified in serializers.py (user_name, email, company, state, city and phone_number) and pass in their respective values but the issue remains the same. I get the same error when I use post request on postman as well as browser. When I use the browser to assess the url `account/register_user/`(the account in the url is from urls.py in Django project) I don't see the fields I specify in serializers.py, instead the only field I see on the browser is `content` and it's not one of the fields in my model.py or serializer.py.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample from the request body?

Comment: Please check, I have added the screenshot of the field I see when I search the url on browser and I dont know why my fields are not displaying. If I click on post, I get the error even without entering any data in content field. When I USE get request on postman and specify the fields and their values, I get the same output.